# Naudio bass only

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I am new to `naudio` library and i don't quite know how to get the `amplitude` form bass frequency only(25-50 HZ).
I am using `naudio` to send live data form my PC to an `arduino`.
The code looks something like this:

```
MMDeviceEnumerator de = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        MMDevice device =de.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
        float volume = (float)device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 255;
        int serial = (int)volume;
        string serialstring = serial.ToString();
```

`Naudio` doesn't have any special attribute for bass only filtering.